# Redirect all files in sub-directory to root via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all files in my domain's sub-directory to the root directory in order to hide the sub-directory from the URL. For example, I would like `www.domain.com/blog/test1.php` to redirect to `www.domain.com/test1.php` and `www.domain.com/blog/test2.php` to redirect to `www.domain.com/test2.php` etc.

How can I achieve this via the `.htaccess` file? Everything I tried until now just redirects all files in the sub-directory to `www.domain.com`.
Thank you for your help.

I've tried using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/$ example.com
RewriteRule /blog/(.*) /$1 [PT]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This all just redirects to `www.example.com`.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I tried for example RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/$ http://example.com/; RewriteRule /blog/(.*) /$1 [PT]; RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] This all just redirects to www.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I am just learning `mod_rewrite` myself, but I think you have an extra '/' in the first `RewriteRule` and an unnecessary hostname in the second.  I believe this is worth a try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) $1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just redirects to the homepage.

Comment: So is this rule making some difference?  Please post the whole .htaccess file with this change in place, then mention what URL you typed and (exactly) what URL you got to.  Also please try something like http://<yourDomain>/blog/foo (where foo is a non-existant blog post) and let us know what *that* returned.